# Get value from annotation failed

Tags: kotlin, annotations

This is annotation definition:

```
@Target(AnnotationTarget.PROPERTY)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@MustBeDocumented
annotation class MyAnno(val desc: String, val comment: String) { }
```

And below is where the `MyAnno` used:

```
class MyAnnoUser {
    @MyAnno(desc = "name", comment = "name comment")
    lateinit var name: String

    @MyAnno(desc = "age", comment = "age comment")
    var age: Int = 0

    @MyAnno(desc =  "money", comment = "money comment")
    var money: Double = 0.0

    @MyAnno(desc =  "gender", comment = "gender comment")
    var gender: Boolean = false

    override fun toString(): String {
        return "(name: $name; age: $age; money: $money; gender: ${if (gender) "men" else "women"})"
    }
}
```

Here's code to read the value in `MyAnno`:

```
class MyAnnoExpression(val obj: Any, val context: Context) {

    val numTypeSet = setOf("Int", "Double", "Byte")

    fun expression() {

        val clazz = obj::class

        clazz.declaredMemberProperties.forEach { prop ->
            val mutableProp = try {
                prop as KMutableProperty<*>
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                null
            } ?: return@forEach

            val desc = mutableProp.findAnnotation<MyAnno>()
            desc?.let {
                val propClassName = mutableProp.returnType.toString().removePrefix("kotlin.")
                when (propClassName) {
                    in numTypeSet -> mutableProp.setter.call(obj, (readProp(it, context) as kotlin.String).toNum(propClassName))
                    "String" -> mutableProp.setter.call(obj, (readProp(it, context) as kotlin.String))
                    "Boolean" -> mutableProp.setter.call(obj, (readProp(it, context) as kotlin.String).toBoolean())
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun readProp(value: MyAnno, context: Context): Any? {
        val prop = Properties()
        val input = context.assets.open("app.properties")
        prop.load(InputStreamReader(input, "utf-8"))
        return prop.get(value.desc)
    }
}
```

Now the Debugger shows me following info of `value` in `readProp(...)` function:

```
@com.demo.basekotlin.MyAnno(comment=age comment, desc=age)
```

But i got exception when read `desc` from `value`:

```
An exception occurs during Evaluate Expression Action : org.jetbrains.eval4j.VOID_VALUE cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.eval4j.AbstractValue
```

I can't find any thing wrong in my code, is there another program setting needed?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you just want to see annotation value for given property.

First, let's declare an annotation.

```
@Target(PROPERTY)
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class PropertyAnnotation(val desc: String)
```

Container:

```
class Container {

    @PropertyAnnotation("Name")
    var name: String? = null

    @PropertyAnnotation("Age")
    var age: Int = -1

    var notAnnotatedProperty: String = "not annotated"
}
```

And finally, code responsible for get all declared properties, then find a properties annotated as `PropertyAnnotation`, cast it to it, and get value from it.

```
fun main() {

    val container = Container()

    container::class.declaredMemberProperties.forEach { property ->
        (property.annotations.find {
            it is PropertyAnnotation
        } as? PropertyAnnotation)?.let {
            println("Property: `$property` is ${it.desc}")
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Property: `var Container.age: kotlin.Int` is Age
Property: `var Container.name: kotlin.String?` is Name
```

Kind ugly. But, let's use more Kotlin pro-dev-features.

Let's create extension function for any not-null type which returns all member property of given type:

```
inline fun <reified T : Any> Any.getMemberProperty(): List<T> {
    return this::class.declaredMemberProperties.mapNotNull { prop ->
        (prop.annotations.find { ann -> ann is T }) as? T
    }
}
```

And now usage:

```
fun main() {

    val container = Container()

    container.getMemberProperty<PropertyAnnotation>().forEach {
        println(it.desc)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not work.  I used your code, and it still show the exception of `An exception occurs during Evaluate Expression Action : org.jetbrains.eval4j.VOID_VALUE cannot be cast to org.jetbrains.eval4j.AbstractValue`  when execute `${it.desc}`

Comment: My Android Studio version is `3.3.1` and kotlin version is `1.3.20`.  Did you add 
dependencies extra?

Comment: It show me another exception of `com.sun.jdi.InternalException : Unexpected JDWP Error: 103` when running on another device.

Comment: I've runned it on clear IntelliJ Idea with Kotlin 1.3. Are you sure your problem is getting property from annotation, not some other code (like invoking via reflection?)

Comment: Of cause it's getting annotation's property. And you can see the property's value on the `Debugger panel`.  It's so weird. I'll retry it in Idea.

Comment: I retried the code in `kotlin/JVM` project with `Idea` and there's no exception out. But the exception comes out every time in `android project` no matter use `Idea(Kotlin (Mobile Android/iOS))` or `Android Studio`.